# Establish conversation between hello-world apps in Docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run my hello-world apps inside Docker: frontend need to consume REST from backend.

I run

```
docker run -p 1337:1337 --net=bridge me/p-dockerfile-advanced-backend:latest
docker run -p 1338:1338 --net=bridge me/p-dockerfile-advanced-frontend:latest http://127.0.0.1:1337
```

I am able to connect to both of them using a browser from the host OS (My desktop Windows 10 x64) :

[image]

[image]

The `http://127.0.0.1:1337` parameter needed for the frontend application to know where the restful services reside. But the app cannot connect to them. I cannot connect too.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\user1> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4b0852253b8a        me/p-dockerfile-advanced-frontend:latest   "/usr/bin/java -ja..."   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:1338->1338/tcp   laughing_noyce
e73f8a6efa24        me/p-dockerfile-advanced-backend:latest    "/usr/bin/java -ja..."   26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes                                youthful_chandrasekhar
PS C:\Users\user1> docker exec -it 4b0852253b8a bash
root@4b0852253b8a:/# apt-get install telnet
<...>
root@4b0852253b8a:/# telnet localhost 1337
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
root@4b0852253b8a:/#
```

Unable to connect, but it should because I specified `--net=bridge` on both containers and backend listen the port 1337 :

```
root@e73f8a6efa24:/# netstat -lntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1337            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
root@e73f8a6efa24:/#
```

PS: I spent almost all day trying to make it work before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 127.0.0.1 address.

Each container is assigned, by default, 2 interfaces: **eth0** and **lo** (the loopback interface with the 127.0.0.1 address).

You need to specify the name or address of the previous container.  For this simple application you may use the ***--link*** option.

```
docker run -p 1337:1337 --name backend me/p-dockerfile-advanced-backend:latest
docker run -p 1338:1338 --link backend:backend me/p-dockerfile-advanced-frontend:latest http://backend:1337
```

Note that the ***--link*** option is deprecated as stated in:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Answer (score 0):

Since these are different containers, you have to expose ports on both of them. Run the first with:

```
docker run -p 1337:1337 --net=bridge me/p-dockerfile-advanced-backend:latest
```

Note that `bridge` is the default network so you it is extra. Both containers will be on the same `bridge` network by default anyway.

Comment: Didn't help. Now I can access first (backend) container from the host OS, but from the second container it unavailable as before. I've added screenshots to the question.